# Python print()/sys.stdout.write() not visible when using logging

Tags: python, logging

I'm using logging extensively in my program. But now I want to write to stdout without using the logging module, but the output does not show up.

Neither:

```
sys.stdout.write( "BOE!" )
```

Nor

```
print( "WAH!" )
```

is working. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Can you post a minimal test case?

Comment: Is this an application, you are running from console? I am new to python. However, if this is a windows based app, where will this get logged?

Comment: Well, that's the thing, in a minimal example it DOES work. So I'm just looking for people who have seen it before. The reason why I assume it's due to logging, is because I've seen it before myself, but only in applications that used logging + it occured only after I started using the logging module.

Comment: It really shouldn't be due to logging (provided that you use the default `logging` module). Make sure that you didn't change sys.stdout anywhere.

Comment: Yes it's a console application. In windows one would have to use a terminal emulator such as cygwin to use it.

Comment: Provided that it works in the minimal example, that would be my thought. But I'm also pretty sure it's not something with stdout, because when I initiate a StreamHandler to stdout, it actually DOES work!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its possible that your Python output is being buffered. Have a look at these two StackOverflow QAs:

1. [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)
2. [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I've already tried flushing the stream

Comment: Additionally I've tried to use stderr, which is unbuffered if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Whoo, something went wrong when I tested that. It actually did the trick. Thanks.